# How can I order a list by one of its sub elements in TCL

Tags: list, sorting, tcl

So I have a string that is treated as a list when I split them  in the \n and it looks like this:
`{aaaa2,bbbb2,cccccc,ddddd\n aaaa3,bbbb4,cccccc,ddddd\n aaaa4,bbbb1,cccccc,ddddd\n aaaa5,bbbb3,cccccc,ddddd}`

I need to reorder this list based on B column, in a way that the lesser value comes first and equal values stay together. Meaning it should be something like this:
`{aaaa4,bbbb1,cccccc,ddddd\n aaaa2,bbbb2,cccccc,ddddd\n aaaa5,bbbb3,cccccc,ddddd\n aaaa3,bbbb4,cccccc,ddddd}`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split each element of your list into a list itself, you can use [`lsort`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm)'s [`-index`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.htm#M13) option:

```
set lst {aaaa2,bbbb2,cccccc,ddddd
    aaaa3,bbbb4,cccccc,ddddd
    aaaa4,bbbb1,cccccc,ddddd
    aaaa5,bbbb3,cccccc,ddddd}
set lst [lmap item $lst { split $item , }]
set lst [lsort -index 1 $lst]
puts [join [lmap sublist $lst { join $sublist , }] \n]
```

will output

```
aaaa4,bbbb1,cccccc,ddddd
aaaa2,bbbb2,cccccc,ddddd
aaaa5,bbbb3,cccccc,ddddd
aaaa3,bbbb4,cccccc,ddddd
```

Comment: Great use of `lmap`. Nice symmetry in splitting and joining.

Comment: That's why `lmap` was added; it makes tasks like this much easier.